NextJS app stuck at compiling phase when adding Tailwind plugins
I'm working on a NextJS app and i put some tailwind configuration in tailwind.config.js file:
const Config = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./sanity/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: "475px",
      },
      colors: {
        primary: {
          100: "#FFE8F0",
          DEFAULT: "#EE2B69",
        },
        secondary: "#FBE843",
        black: {
          100: "#333333",
          200: "#141413",
          300: "#7D8087",
          DEFAULT: "#000000",
        },
        white: {
          100: "#F7F7F7",
          DEFAULT: "#FFFFFF",
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        "work-sans": ["var(--font-work-sans)"],
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      boxShadow: {
        100: "2px 2px 0px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        200: "2px 2px 0px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0)",  
        300: "2px 2px 0px 2px rgb(238, 43, 105)",
      },
    },
  },
  // plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
};

export default Config;


it runs localhost with no issue, but if i uncomment the line where it requires plugins it gets stuck at compiling phase, what's wrong here ?

using import instead of require solved the issue for me:
import tailwindAnimate from "tailwindcss-animate";
import tailwindTypography from "@tailwindcss/typography";

const Config = {
  ...
  plugins: [tailwindAnimate, tailwindTypography],
};

export default Config;

This is the proper way to do this when using ES Modules
